# html-to-image node giving window not defined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I am trying to use [html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) to test a sample DOM to Image conversion. I have the following code that supplies a DOM element to htmlToImage. However, I get window not defined error as follows:

Error

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at px (.../Projects/dom/node_modules/html-to-image/lib/utils.js:105:17)

Code snippet

```
const htmlToImage = require ('html-to-image')
const download =  require('downloadjs')
const DomParser = require('dom-parser')
const parser = new DomParser();
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

let node= new JSDOM('<div id="a" style ="height:200px"> WASSUP </div>')
htmlToImage.toPng(node)
  .then(function (dataUrl) {
  download(dataUrl, 'my-node.png');
});
```

Can someone give me some ideas on what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to use `html-to-image` on server side. But, as I know, this library work only on client side.